# Inkscape/svg: convert embedded images to external linked files

Tags: inkscape, svg

I have a .svg with embedded images (which was imported from a .pdf).
I'd like to convert all the embedded images to external linked files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on the file(s) and choose to 'Extract Image'. There's also an extension for it at Extensions > Images > Extract.

Comment: It doesn't do anything for this file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lfXbhopAntQMqiZyMgR97ylg1z10xJ3s

Comment: Yes, that image is just a clone of an image. Release the mask, unlink the clone and try again.

Comment: Worked; cool, thanks.