# Embed linked raster images in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, raster, embed

I have an svg file with many linked raster images, I would like to embed them because the browser is not supporting linked images. Is there an automated way to embed all the linked images?

[Inkscape/svg: convert embedded images to external linked files](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/136875/inkscape-svg-convert-embedded-images-to-external-linked-files) do the opposit of what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Select all your images, right-click one on the canvas and select 'Embed Image'. Now all selected images should be embedded.

[image: Screenshot of right-click menu with 'Embed Image' highlighted.]

To quickly select all images at once, you can use the <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd> 'Find/Replace' panel. Just set the 'Scope' to 'All', expand the 'Options' section, un-check 'All types' under 'Object types' and select 'Images'. Now when you click the 'Find' button while keeping the input at the top empty, it should select all images.

[image: 'Find/Replace' dialog with above mentioned settings highlighted.]

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that if you go to `Extensions` `Images` `Embed Images` you can embed all your images at once or just the one you selected.
[image]

And then:

[image]